# How to install Windows 10 alongside with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I just wanted to ask is it possible to install window 10 beta alongside with ubuntu 14.04 or there will be some problem(boot related). If its possible will the procedure be exactly same as installing some other windows on a single ubuntu drive?

Answer (score 1):

It is **NOT** possible to install Windows on the same Partition with Ubuntu.

*The things you **CAN** do however are:*

1. Create a separate partition from unallocated space on the hard drive or shrink the ubuntu partition to get back unallocated space and then create a partition for windows.
2. or Install windows inside a Virtual Machine (Virtualbox or VMware) inside Ubuntu. This way you don't have to play with hard disk partitions.

**Updating GRUB after installing Windows:**

Installing windows will rewrite MBR n you would not get the GRUB bootloader screen to select which OS to boot into. For this see **[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)**.